# Selecting rows based on last occurence of a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks something like this,

```
id   desc
1    Description
1    02.09.2017 15:00 abcd
1    this is a sample description
1    which is continued here also
1    
1    Description
1    01.09.2017 12:00 absd
1    this is another sample description
1    which might be continued here
1    or here
1
2    Description
2    09.03.2017 12:00 abcd
2    another sample again
2    and again
2
2    Description
2    08.03.2017 12:00 abcd
2    another sample again
2    and again times two
```

Basically, there is an id and the rows contain the information in a very unstructured format. I want to extract the description which is after the last "Description" row and store that in 1 row. The resulting dataframe would look something like this:

```
id  desc
1   this is another sample description which might be continued here or here
2   another sample again and again times two
```

From what I am able to think, I might have to use groupby but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: We can't figure out the logic of joining texts based on mere output. Specify the logic of joining.

Comment: @Zero Fixed it. I made a mistake in the output row.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I want to extract all the text following the last description tag for a particular id. In my case, the text has not been formatted properly and is split up in different rows, hence i need to put it in one row. I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the positions of last `Description` and join the rows using `str.cat`

```
In [2840]: def lastjoin(x):
      ...:     pos = x.desc.eq('Description').cumsum().idxmax()
      ...:     return x.desc.loc[pos+2:].str.cat(sep=' ')
      ...:

In [2841]: df.groupby('id').apply(lastjoin)
Out[2841]:
id
1    this is another sample description which might...
2            another sample again and again times two
dtype: object
```

To have columns use `reset_index`

```
In [3216]: df.groupby('id').apply(lastjoin).reset_index(name='desc')
Out[3216]:
   id                                               desc
0   1  this is another sample description which might...
1   2          another sample again and again times two
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is what i was looking for but there's a slight problem. I want to retain both my column headers but they are not there after i do this